# Is there a tag for infoleaks?

Tags: discussion, tags

I know there is a [data-leakage](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-leakage) tag, but that is not what I am looking for. I am wondering if there are any tags that encompass traditional information leakage in binary exploitation, for example leaking stack cookies, base pointers, heap memory layout, etc. In the meantime, I created [infoleak](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/infoleak) for [a question](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/197876/165253).

Comment: what would be the differentiation between those two tags?

Comment: @AviD According to the tag wiki, _Data-leakage is the uncontrolled, unauthorized transmission of classified information from a data centre or computer system to the outside_. This sounds more like information disclosure, and not information leakage in the binary exploitation sense. Looking through the list of questions with that tag backs that assertion.

Comment: So I'm not clear on what the new tag would introduce? Maybe I'm just not familiar with that niche...

Comment: @AviD It's a very specific kind of security vulnerability. [Example](https://grsecurity.net/the_infoleak_that_mostly_wasnt.php)

Comment: Sure, but its just a specific kind of data leakage... ?

Comment: @AviD In the same way that information theft or data remanence are just a specific kind of data leakage, but we have tags for both of those. From looking through everything in [tag:data-leakage], I could not find one of them that was actually discussing the type of vulnerability called an infoleak.

Comment: okay I will take your word for it, outside my expertise :-)

Comment: Could you add some usage guidance for the tag that makes it abundantly clear what it's about? I don't know the area, but if there is a more specific name I think that would be good. Like [binary-exploitation-infoleak] or whatever. I don't know what it is, though, so don't take my naming suggestions to seriously...